# Methods arrays in java

Tags: java

I'm practicing for my final exam on java this semester and am doing some problems from the book.

Write a method that returns true if the arrays list1 and list2 are strictly identical, using the following header:

public static boolean equals(int[] list1, int[] list2)

Here's my code. It gives me "illigal start of statement" next to the return statement. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class StrictlyIdenticalArrays {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

        int[] list1 = new int[12];
        int[] list2 = new int[12];

        System.out.print("Enter list1: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
            list1[i] = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter list2 ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
            list2[i] = input.nextInt();

        if (equals(list1, list2) == true)
            System.out.print("Two lists are strictly identical");
        else
            System.out.print("Two lists are not strictly identical");
    }

    public static boolean equals(int[] list1, int[] list2) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            if (list1[i] == list2[i])

        } return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your braces....

Comment: You don't have any statement after `if(list1[i] == list2[i])` -- what would you like to do if that evaluates to `true`?.

Comment: Format your code - your error will become clear. Also, what happens when your arrays have a different number of elements to `12`? Further, why call an array a `list`? There already is a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

Comment: if it evaluates to true, it prints "Two lists are strictly identical". Got that fixed with Mohammed's help, but now I can't break from the initial prompt to move to the second one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have only to use this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        if (list1[i] != list2[i])return false;

    } return true;
```

here you will loop until the end of list is reached when every members are strictly identical and return by true , but if only one member found none identique it return a false. return statement bock method execution whenever is called .

Comment: and dynamically use list1.length in the loop (for).12 is not a error but no cute for a good developper

Comment: that helped. no compile errors, but now after the first prompt, after I enter the numbers and press enter, it doesn't break to go to the second prompt

Comment: @Peter add a System.out.Println(); before the System.out.print("Enter List2 :");

Comment: @Peter take a look about how to use stackoverflow [http://stackoverflow.com/tour]

Comment: Did I do something wrong.... Sorry if I did. I think I'll just add an exception for the input to break when a negative value is entered. The System.out.println() did not work out. It doesn't get pass the initial input. Thanks though

Comment: Or I'll use the unicode for "enter" as a value to break to the next one

Comment: @Peter is only to show you how to use nothing wrong, please tell me what do you mean by it does not go to the second prompt ???

Comment: well, when you run the program, it displays "Enter list1:"   and I start putting values in, and regardless of how many values I put, it never gets to prompt me "Enter list2:' for the second list

Answer (score 1):

For a correct implementation of

```
public static boolean equals(int[] list1, int[] list2)
```

you need to do the following:

- First check that the arrays have equal `length`s; if not `return false`.
- Next, loop through the arrays, using either `i < list1.length` or `i < list2.length` as the termination expression for the loop.
- Within the loop, check that the elements of the arrays are equal; if not `return false`.
- Finally, after the loop has been finished, `return true`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (list1[i] == list2[i])
```

is not closing statement,

it should be closed by brackets after

```
if (list1[i] == list2[i]) {}
```

or by semicolon

```
if (list1[i] == list2[i]);
```

but more importantly, why are you checking that condition if you are not taking any decision based on that

Comment: The semicolon is mandatory after the `if`, isn't it? Otherwise it's not an empty statement. Does the brackets-alone version compile?

Answer (score 0):

You method is not really working the way you want it to. You have to change it a little to make it return true or false

You method will look like this:

```
public static boolean equals(int[] list1, int[] list2) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list1.length; i++) 
    {
        if (list1[i] != list2[i])
           return false;
    } 

    return true;
}
```